# Логирование в Log4j2

Tags: java, apache, gradle, log4j, логирование

Хочу добавить в проект логирование, выбрали **Log4j2**.

Добавил библиотеки:

- ***'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.3'***
- ***'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.3'***

в зависимости Gradle и создал файл конфигурации ***log4j2.xml*** в котором указал записывать логи в файлы (для фатальных отдельно, а дебаг отдельно).

Что еще нужно сделать чтобы в файлы начали записыватся логи?

Хотелось бы логировать все класы как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Все оказалось довольно просто.
Необходимо зарегистрировать Логер в классе в виде:

Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

и потом можно использовать переменную logger в коде.
Например при перехвате Exception:

catch (Exception e) {log.error("Error"+e);}